# Is there a way to respond to an HTTP Post on an ASP page?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

We are developing an SMS communication platform to communicate with our customers using Twilio.  We have 30 - 50 folks who need to communicate with our 3500 customers. Requests to send messages are put into a SQL table, and a VB.NET app takes these messages and sends them via Twilio.  An API recieves Twilio's updates/replies/status changes and posts them to the SQL table. The API is on the "outside" (in terms of security) alongside our web server, not on our internal network.  The VB.NET app is on the inside. We then have an ASP "chat" page (on the inside) that the reps and dispatch folks can use to communicate back and forth with the customers.

Now for my question. The ASP page reads the conversations for specific phone numbers from the SQL table. I can't have the API communicate directly with the ASP page, since the ASP page is on our internal network, and the API is on the "outside" to satisfy security concerns.  So currently I have the VB.NET app sending an HTTP POST to the webpage to signal a new message or status change.  The post contains the phone numbers involved, so only the pages with the correct conversation can respond.  The ASP page gets the POST and correctly reads the data, but I can't seem to make it trigger an event.  Ideally I would have the POST trigger an event to refresh the conversation. Using a debugger, I can see the code going through the motions, but no data is updated. I assume this is because the POST is to the ASP page, not to the server.  Javascript doesn't seem to know that this post happened, so I can't seem to trigger an event with Javascript either.

Here's the code for the post from the VB.NET app:

```
wc = New WebClient()
Dim resp = wc.UploadValues(Chat_URL & url_suffix, "POST", keys)
```

Here's the code on the ASP page to try to catch the post

```
 If Request.HttpMethod = "POST" And Not Request.Form("posttime") Is Nothing Then
    Dim post_jf_phone As String = ""
    Dim post_cust_phone As String = ""

    If Not Request.Form("jfphone") Is Nothing Then
        post_jf_phone = "+" & Request.Form("jfphone").Trim
    End If
    If Not Request.Form("custphone") Is Nothing Then
        post_cust_phone = "+" & Request.Form("custphone").Trim
    End If

    'If these are the numbers we're viewing...
    If post_cust_phone = TxtCustPhone.Text And post_jf_phone = TxtJFPhone.Text Then
        Load_Data(TxtCustPhone.Text)
    End If
End If
```

On the initial form load event, the Load_Data function works perfectly, but nothing happens when it's fired from the HTTP POST.  I've tried a Response.Redirect and Server.TransferRequest to reload the page, but these don't work either.

Sorry to be long-winded here, but any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Short answer: websockets. asp.net-specific answer: SignalR

Comment: That's helpful - thank you!